# How to manually upload thumbnails to dspace?

Tags: dspace

Is there a way to upload a thumbnails for a items created in dspace, I not interest in use media-filter, the thumbnails are created in photoshop for customer request

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Edit Item screen.  From the Bitstreams tab, you can upload a new bitstream.

Specify that you would like to add the item to the Thumbnails bundle.

[image]

The thumbnail name should match the name of the original bitstream with ".jpg" appended to the filename.